# On reload different width of portfolio text

Tags: javascript, onclick, portfolio

You have helped me out great with the code for my portfolio website!!

There is only one problem remaining that I discovered the other day.

When you click a portfolio item it opens. If you close it, it closes. But if you open the same portfolio item again the text width becomes really narrow!

Comment: works fine in firefox latest v.?? which browser you are using..??

Comment: Chrome and Safari on Mac (don't know if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in IE10 and FireFox.

I tried on the bottom-left-hand corner picture (P7).
It seems chrome (for exemple) doesn't like max-width.

You could try to replace

```
#p7{
max-width:850px;
}
```

by

```
#p7{
width:850px;
}
```

Comment: Logical answer, but I need the max-width so my site is responsive when scalling the browser!

Comment: I fixed it myself! I used max-width on the p1, p2, etc... I used min-width: 100% on the wrapper!

Comment: Not solved on your website for me : http://stilld.nl/ Maybe you didn't update it yet ?

Answer (score 0):

an edit in style.css:711 will solve the issue

```
#alldescriptions {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 850px;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. I don't have a file called dialog.js

Comment: I fixed it myself! I used max-width on the p1, p2, etc... I used min-width: 100% on the wrapper! Your solution would compromise the responsiveness of the page;)